# Shortcut to Namespacing a class in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, how is it possible to namespace a controller class with the following line of code without having MyModule defined anywhere?

```
class MyModule::MyClass < ApplicationController
```

I know it would raise a NameError in Ruby (since you are calling a module that doesn't exist), but for some reason it works in Rails. What is the hidden mechanics that make this "shortcut" namespacing possible?

Comment: Did you read this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called [autoloading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html). From the constant name, Rails guesses the path name where its definition might be, and attempts to load it.

Particularly, namespacing like your `MyModule` would be expected to correspond to a directory name, within which the file that has the definition of `MyClass` is expected to exist.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're making a controller here, and Rails is very particular about file naming conventions for controllers. It'd have to be in `app/controllers/my_module/my_class_controller.rb`.

If this isn't working, you can also define the module in-line, it doesn't matter if it's also defined elsewhere.

```
module MyModule
  class MyClassController < ApplicationController
```